# python sorting lists according to number of elements

Tags: python, list, sorting

I need to sort  lists in a set according to the number of elements they have.
Here are some of my lists:

```
['RB', 'RB', 'VBD', 'TO', 'PRP', 'RB']
['PRP', 'RB', 'RB', 'JJ']
['PRP', 'MD', 'RB', 'VB', 'PRP$', 'NN', 'RB', 'IN', 'NN']
['RB', 'DT', 'NN']
['PRP', 'RB', 'VBP', 'PRP']
['PRP', 'RB', 'VBD', 'IN', 'DT']
['MD', 'RB', 'VB', 'IN', 'NNP', 'RB']
['RB', 'CD']
```

And this is the output sought:

```
['RB', 'CD']
['RB', 'DT', 'NN']
['PRP', 'RB', 'RB', 'JJ']
['PRP', 'RB', 'VBP', 'PRP']
['PRP', 'RB', 'VBD', 'IN', 'DT']
['MD', 'RB', 'VB', 'IN', 'NNP', 'RB']
['RB', 'RB', 'VBD', 'TO', 'PRP', 'RB']
['PRP', 'MD', 'RB', 'VB', 'PRP$', 'NN', 'RB', 'IN', 'NN']
```

The lists are sorted from the shortest to the largest, according to the numbers of elements on them.

Can somebody help?... I did some research but couldn't find my way around it. Thanks a lot. There are solutions for length of strings, but not elements in lists

Comment: `sorted(yourlist,key=len)`

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions

Comment: Please perform a minimum level of research prior to posting a question, such as pasting the title you intend to use for it into a Google search.

Comment: I performed the search. The solutions given are for strings, not for elements in lists. The solutions given are not working. There is much rush to put negative marks on questions, I think

Comment: @norpa: `len` works the same way on lists.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `sorted()` function, using the length of each element as the sort key:

```
sorted(the_list, key=len)
```

Example:

```
>>> the_list = [
...     ['RB', 'RB', 'VBD', 'TO', 'PRP', 'RB'],
...     ['PRP', 'RB', 'RB', 'JJ'],
...     ['PRP', 'MD', 'RB', 'VB', 'PRP$', 'NN', 'RB', 'IN', 'NN'],
...     ['RB', 'DT', 'NN'],
...     ['PRP', 'RB', 'VBP', 'PRP'],
...     ['PRP', 'RB', 'VBD', 'IN', 'DT'],
...     ['MD', 'RB', 'VB', 'IN', 'NNP', 'RB'],
...     ['RB', 'CD']
... ]
>>> sorted(the_list, key=len)
[['RB', 'CD'], ['RB', 'DT', 'NN'], ['PRP', 'RB', 'RB', 'JJ'], ['PRP', 'RB', 'VBP', 'PRP'], ['PRP', 'RB', 'VBD', 'IN', 'DT'], ['RB', 'RB', 'VBD', 'TO', 'PRP', 'RB'], ['MD', 'RB', 'VB', 'IN', 'NNP', 'RB'], ['PRP', 'MD', 'RB', 'VB', 'PRP$', 'NN', 'RB', 'IN', 'NN']]
```

Comment: I don't have my lists in a list of lists. Do I have to create a list of lists? I was hoping to find a more straightforward solution

Comment: @norpa: Where do you have them, then?

Comment: @norpa The lists can be in any iterable. This includes lists, tuples, and generators. I'm not sure what you mean by "straightforward." What are your lists stored in currently?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of the lists and then sort as given below:

```
a = ['RB', 'RB', 'VBD', 'TO', 'PRP', 'RB']
b = ['PRP', 'RB', 'RB', 'JJ']

combo = [a,b]

sorted_list = sorted(combo, key=len)
```